# Error caught on signal handler:TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode got instance

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapinghub

Getting this strange error when I run my code in scrapy cloud. Not sure how to debug it. There is no reference to line in the spider code.
I assume it is about saving an item and smth general as no url is indicated. Moreover the spider runs ok and provides results after this error.
Any help is appreciated.

```
    [scrapy.utils.signal] Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.item_scraped of <sh_scrapy.extension.HubstorageExtension object at 0x7fcdc33abf50>> Less
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/extension.py", line 45, in item_scraped
    item = self.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 304, in export_item
    result = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 75, in _get_serialized_fields
    value = self.serialize_field(field, field_name, item[field_name])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 284, in serialize_field
    return serializer(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 290, in _serialize_value
    return dict(self._serialize_dict(value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/exporters.py", line 300, in _serialize_dict
    key = to_bytes(key) if self.binary else key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 117, in to_bytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got instance
```

Here is the item I yield:

```
  {response.meta['url'] : {"rss_categories": [], "int_links" : int_links, "ext_links" : ext_links, "all_links" : len(all_links), "email" : email, "url" : url, "social_media":[{"twitter" : twitter,"facebook" : facebook, "instagram" : instagram, "pinterest" : pinterest, "youtube" : youtube }],"rss_atom" : rss_atom, "title" : title, "MetaDescription" : MetaDescription, "descr" : descr, "keywords" :[{}]}}
```

Comment: what kind of item are you yielding?

Comment: it is complex dict structure.

Comment: do you know if it's serializable, because it seems to me that's the problem

Comment: I am not sure what serializable is first of all. I have added the item into my main post. Please check.

Comment: What's that `MetaDescription`?

Comment: it is meta keywords. MetaDescription = response.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords']/@content").extract_first()

Comment: I think that I would need to see the spider's code to be able to help you, but I would debug it commenting most of the fields and see if the error is still there (also disabling pipelines or any other middleware that might change the item) and add the fields progressively.